# Object Not Maintaining Assigned Values

Tags: javascript, loops, object, properties, variable-assignment

I am looping through an array to create another array of objects in a modified format.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 37; i++) { // create 37 boxes for days of the month and nearby dates
  room_reservations[i] = {};
  var this_date = getDate();
  var res_count = 0;
  for (var res_index = 0; res_index < reservations.length; res_index++) {
    var this_res = reservations[res_index];
    // bad assignment location
    // res_room = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this_res));
    if (this_res.checkin <= this_date && this_res.checkout > this_date) {
      for (var k = 0; k < this_res.rooms.length; k++) {
        var res_room = {};
        res_room = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this_res));
        var this_room = res_room.rooms[k];
        res_room.room_index = k;
        var traveler_count = this_room.travelers.length;
        console.log('traveler_count: ', traveler_count);
        res_room.traveler_count = traveler_count;
        //traveler_counts[i][res_room.room_name] = traveler_count;
        console.log('res_room.traveler_count: ', res_room.traveler_count);
        var room_name = this_room.room_name;
        console.log('room_name: ', room_name);
        res_room.room_name = room_name;
        console.log('res_room: ', res_room);
        room_reservations[i][res_room.room_name] = res_room;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially, I console log the object property traveler_count and get the correct value.  But when logging the entire object, the property value is incorrect.  It's like it grabs the value from the next loop.

[image]

How do I fix this?  It is not just the logging.  The values being set are wrong in the room_reservations array.  For example, I set the attribute name to res_room.room_name and the value to res_room.   But the attribute name does not match the value in the object.

[image]

Please help.  Thx

Comment: It appears that `res_room` is a global variable (line `7`). Can you try making it local with `var`, since you're changing it every iteration?

Comment: While I agree that that's good idea, I don't see how it could cause this problem. He's not calling any external functions that might modify the variable.

Comment: You're using the same `res_room` object each time through that inner `for` loop.

Comment: I suggest reading this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/642/debugging/2131/breakpoints#t=201608222347162824112)

Comment: javascript variable hoisting (google it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same `res_room` object every time through the `for (var k)` loop. So all the properties in `res_room[i]` are referring to the same object, which you modify in place. You need to make a copy of the object when you assign it.

```
room_reservations[i][res_room.room_name] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res_room));
```

Comment: I modified the code to use a local variable and put the assignment inside of the third loop.  It works now.  Thanks!!!!